# How can i filter query by another related table Yii CDbCriteria?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

This my mysql tables structure.
[image]

I want sum of ordered products quantity and amount by a user like this.
[image]

My codes is here, but is not true.

```
<?php
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
 $criteria->with = 'orders';
 $criteria->together = true;
 if(!empty($_GET['email'])){
     $email = CHtml::encode($_GET['email']);
     if($user = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$email))){
          $criteria->addSearchCondition('orders.user_id', $user->id);
     }
 }
 $products = Products::model()->findAll($criteria);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u have good relations in models and same names u can try someth similar to (but i started from Orders not from Products - u can start from Products too) :

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 'SUM(t.amount) as amount_sum, SUM(oP.quantity) as quantity_sum, p.title, p.code';
         $criteria->with = ['orderProducts'=>['alias'=>'oP'], 'orderProducts.Products'=>['alias'=>'p']];
         $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->group = 't.id, oP.product_id, p.id';
         if(!empty($_GET['email'])){
             $email = CHtml::encode($_GET['email']);
             if($user = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$email))){
                  $criteria->addSearchCondition('t.user_id', $user->id);
             }
         }
         $orders = Orders::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

PS: U need too add attributes to models: public $amount_sum and public $quantity_sum.

Comment: tank you. there is an error. Active record "Orders" is trying to select an invalid column "p.title". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.